# Declaring Variables with Equality Operators

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have so many resources on the internet but cannot find the help I need. maybe my keywords for searching aren't accurate or maybe it isn't available. I am using Adobe Acrobat DC and creating an interactive form for my company.

here's my question:

can I declare a variable like this:

```
var x = (y = z)
```

thank you, in advance.

Comment: Yes! But then `x`, `y` and `z` will all have the same value (the value of `z`)

Comment: yes! that really is my goal for this form. i want the value of lets say, field y is equal to the value of a dropdown field z and be stored in var x. one last question: how can i write this code? will it be  var x = (this.getField("y").value = this.getField("z").value)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var y=z;
var x=y;
```

Cheers!

Comment: `z is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can do it. However, it may not work.

It depends on how the variables z and y are defined. If they are field objects, it won't work at all, if they are field values, neither.

So, the question is, what do you actually want to accomplish?

The answer by Mãdãlin Novac is in fact a better way to define it. You simply need to have the variable z defined beforehand. This under the assumption that it is what you want to accomplish.